# Stack as an array of nodes

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, binary-tree

I am taking a Data Structures course using C language.
I was reading about a certain implementation of Stacks in a Binary Tree (more specifically, an Expression Tree)

This is the structure of the node

```
{
 struct Node *right,*left;
 char data;
} Node;
```

The following function :

```
Node * createExpressionTree(char* a,int len)
{
    Node *temp;
    Node *stack[100];
    int top=-1,i=0;
    .
    .
    .
    temp->left=pop(stack,&top);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I'm assuming `stack` here is a two-dimensional array of Nodes and top is obviously of type int.

Now in this function:

```
Node* pop(Node** stack,char *t)
{
    Node* temp;
    temp=stack[*t];
    --*t;
    return temp;
}
```

I am so lost now. Why is the second argument of the function of type string (array of characters) but in the function call an `int` value is passed.

and how does `*t` work as an index for `stack`.
And what is the meaning of `--*t;`?

In the C course that i have taken, arrays were covered but i don't understand the way the `stack` array works in this case, the indices and all.

Can i get an elaboration on the above? Thank you in advance

Edit:
People seem to be confused about the combination of binary trees with stacks.
But the program is converting a given postfix expression to expression tree using stacks 
The program gives me the correct string output with the above parameters.

Comment: Stack and binary tree? That's a bit like using a hammer for getting a screw into a wall. It somehow works, but a screw-driver (i. e. linked list, or even better, array based solution) would be better tool for...

Comment: `char* t` is a pointer to character, then later on, `*t` dereferences the pointer, i. e. you get the value pointed to. `--*t` first dereferences the pointer and then decrements the value found there, i. e. makes a `6` from a `7`, and, appropriate character set provided (there are some where characters are not following one another alphabetically), a `a` from a `b`...

Comment: The mix of `int` and `char` seems strange. Anyway - `--*t;` decrements the value the `t` points to.

Comment: Considering that `t` actually points to an int (not a char), it will just decrement one of those bytes inside the int, leaving the other ones unchanged, on a little endian machine this will be the least significant byte...

Comment: The `char *t` declaration in `pop` is clearly a mistake, it should have been `int *t`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError no my program gives me the output as a string when I use char *t only